# correct visualization of tableview and UIWebView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiwebview

How guys!
Show the following code that I could run with the help of you, but now I come over the first two problems:

and made it work "correctly" but not if this good visualization, since the selection first shows me that I did, and again the same selection.
then I hit another cell of the table and shows me the before and after he had already selected.

What I am is that I omitted this line of code and does a double transition, but I have to give back to click the cell to go directly to the link.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

   index = indexPath.row

   this line -->self.performSegueWithIdentifier("regresar", sender: self)
}
```

What I need is that no double transition, because when I go back I have to go through the eye as I mentioned previously charged up

The second is:

I now another problem arises when I view the page with the UIWebView do not load properly, because the page that charge is responsiba and this happens only with the first page that charge, the other displays them "correctly"
I have no idea if either the emulator, thanks for your help.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you have a segue hooked up to the cell in the storyboard? If so, you shouldn't be calling performSegueWithIdentifier in code.

Comment: if so is, I connect with ViewController, but if I omit the line that is there, I have to click twice the same cell to send me the option I want, in this case a url

`self.performSegueWithIdentifier("regresar", sender: self)`

Comment: take as a basis the answer to this question
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539712/how-to-use-navigationcontroller-to-show-up-a-webview-when-i-choose-one-cell-from)